# how can I constraint a view to the center of another views bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to have an image always perfectly centered on top of the bottom of another image.

My first thought was setting the background image's bottom constraint to, for example 100dp from another view, and then the foreground image's bottom constraint to 50dp from the same view, and set it's height to 100dp.
This way it will always be on the center of the background image's bottom center, but I am making the foreground view not responsive by giving it a fixed size, which is something I would like to avoid.

Another thought I had was to constraint both the top and bottom of the foreground image to the bottom of the background image, but then the view just collapses.
I can't find any settings that would allow that to work.

*I need to keep a ratio for the foreground image.

Comment: Could you post an image visualizing what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here:

https://gist.github.com/writtmeyer/f5971266394b2316eb01b566cdeff2a0

It suggests a clever way if using a dummy view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by constraining your view to the start and end of the target, so that it will keep centered to it. Here's a sample:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/targetView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/targetView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/targetView" />
```

Comment: Thank you William but that it not how I needed that. I've attached the correct answer, if you're interested you can see what was my actual problem and what was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foregroundImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/backgroundImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/backgroundImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/backgroundImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/backgroundImage"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```